# Wired Update Panel Postback Issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have developed a web site and used update panel controls on all pages.  The site was working fine and partial rendering was also working fine.  But today update panel just stopped doing any post back.  I don't know if this has anything to do with Performance Analysis, since I was experimenting with it yesterday.

I am using Asp.NET AJAX 3.5 framework, ToolkitScriptManager on all pages.

Things I tried doing.

1.) Reloaded Binary for AJAX Control Toolkit

2.) Tried to reload update panel

3.) Page methods within Update Panel seems to work.  And Autocomplete Extender is working appropriately.

4.) I did backed up my code from few weeks back.  It is working as expected.  So I tried to copy web.config from my backup and checked it on latest code.  Still not working.

Currently on any page whenever I select an item from a dropdownlist it is not doing a typical asynchronous postback and doesn't load other dependent dropdownlists.

Also update panel is not working on any of my pages.  There seems to be an issue related to web.config but not sure though(I also added a new web config file but not working).

Any help in related to this would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem. Cause: I have written "Response.write()" in my master page. I was able to track in Chrome Console window and this was error: Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled. I removed response.write and it works as it was supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing as @Mitul but it was a Response.Redirect().
It works on localhost but not in production.

I added and works everywhere !

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkAddProduct" />
    </Triggers>
```

The "lnkAddProduct" is a LinkButton in a Panel.